# print,printto on MAC OS X

Tags: c++, xcode

I'm trying to call printing of a document from my C++(XCode) application on MAC.I'm currently using Launch Services framework,but I didn't noticed where is printto option(flag).Is this supported by Launch Services at all?Is there some other way to do this?

Thanks,
Marko

Comment: What do you mean "printto option"? Show what you're doing with Launch Services.

Comment: I mean printing document to particular printer(not the defaul one,like ShellExecute(printto) on Win),here some code

Comment: std::string originalString("/Users/mahmood1/Desktop/3.rtf");
    
OSStatus err = ::FSPathMakeRef (
                             (const UInt8 *)originalString.c_str(),
                              &ref,
                              false
                             );


    ::LSLaunchFSRefSpec spec ={  NULL,
                            1,
                          &ref,
                            NULL,
                            2, //this is flag for printing
                          asyncRefCon };
::LSOpenFromRefSpec ( &spec, &outLaunchedRef );

Answer (score 0):

According to [Technical Note TN2082: The Enhanced Print Apple Event](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/mac/library/#technotes/tn2002/tn2082.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003113) (in the legacy docs), you should be able to specify a `keyAEPropData` parameter of type `kPMPrinterAEType` whose value is a `PMPrinter` reference.

That TechNote is a bit unclear, though. It seems as though the `keyAEPropData` parameter carries both the print settings and the printer. The receiver can retrieve both pieces of information by coercing the parameter's "actual" value to two different types. That raises the question of whether you can specify the parameter value with just `kPMPrinterAEType` and have it work, or if it needs to be some other type.

Anyway, you can construct an `AEDesc` for the parameter and pass it in to `LSOpenFromRefSpec()` in the `passThruParams` field of the `LSLaunchFSRefSpec` structure.

It may help to use the Script Editor to send an enhanced print Apple Event to a test application which then dumps that event. That may clear up how exactly the parameter is constructed, so you can construct it in the same way.

Comment: can I use this to print to some printer?

Comment: Yes, a `PMPrinter` reference is from Core Printing. You could use Core Printing to obtain the PMPrinter reference to put into the `AEDesc` that you supply to `LSOpenFromRefSpec()`. And, yes, I believe this is how you would direct the printing to a specific printer. You'll have to experiment to figure out exactly how to make it work.